# What does the letter "D" next to the VOR frequency and name mean?

Tags: approach, aeronautical-charts, vor

[image]

In most charts there is the letter D next to the VOR freq. What does this mean? I assume the H and L in brackets in other charts mean high and low VORs (correct me if im wrong). But what does the D itself stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're specifically referencing a Jeppesen chart, we'll go right to the source.

Jeppesen's "[Introduction to Jeppesen Navigation Charts](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/glossary-legends.pdf)" has a glossary and explanation of all terms and symbols.

The answer to your question reads as follows:

> 1 — VORDME. Low and High/Low charts include a Compass Rose with VHF
>   Navaids. Shadow box indicates navaid is airway component, with
>   frequency, identifier, Morse code and INS coordinates. Small "D"
>   indicates DME/TACAN. Class indicated by: (T) Terminal, (L) Low, (H)
>   High.

So, the D indicates that the VOR has a co-located DME radio.

(and, no need for correction to your assumption: the H and L in brackets do, indeed, refer to a High or Low class of VFR)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Jeppesen guide](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf):

> [image]
>
> 7 — A letter "D" indicates [DME capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measuring_equipment) with an asterisk indicating part time.